# How can i increase zoom in Apple Mapkit with multiple annotations in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, mapkit

[image]

I tried this code, here I increase MKCoordinateSpan to 200 - 200, but my application got crashed, can someone please help me.

```
 func setupMap(hotelListData:[HotelListData], cityLocation: 
                CLLocationCoordinate2D )
   {

    let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: cityLocation, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 200, longitudeDelta: 200))
    mapView.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)

    //Set Multiple Annotation
    for data in hotelListData {
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.title = data.hotel?.name
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(data.hotel?.latitude ?? 0.0), longitude: Double(data.hotel?.longitude ?? 0.0))
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }
}
```

**Update:**

I changed span from (latitudinalMeters & longitudinalMeters) and got the desired results :-

Now one can found here :

i)Set multiple Annotations to apple maps.

ii)Adjust Zoom with the desired location.

```
  func setupMap(hotelListData:[HotelListData], cityLocation: 
                 CLLocationCoordinate2D ){
    
    let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: cityLocation, latitudinalMeters: CLLocationDistance(exactly: 15000)!, longitudinalMeters: CLLocationDistance(exactly: 15000)!)
    mapView.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)

    //Set Multiple Annotation
    for data in hotelListData {
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.title = data.hotel?.name
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(data.hotel?.latitude ?? 0.0), longitude: Double(data.hotel?.longitude ?? 0.0))
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }
}
```

Comment: Umm... there are only 180 degrees of latitude on earth. What are you doing with a latitude span of 200 degrees? You want to zoom ***in***, don't you?

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, I want to zoom in, I thought increasing or decreasing it could affect zoom, can you please help me, what exactly I need to do for zoom.

Comment: Yes, changing it would affect the zoom. But you need to change it to a _sensible number_. How far in do you want to zoom? How many degrees of latitude and longitude should the map span?

Comment: I need to zoom it where I can see a particular area in a city so that the user will be able to see all the annotations clearly. what numbers do I need to pass there to get the result?

Comment: I don't remember exactly what I put in my app several years.  Try setting each to 100.0.

Comment: @ElTomato, I tried setting each to 100.0 but did not get the desired results now I am trying **MKCoordinateRegion(center: cityLocation, latitudinalMeters: CLLocationDistance(exactly: 5000)!, longitudinalMeters: CLLocationDistance(exactly: 5000)!)** Hope it will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`longitudeDelta`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkcoordinatespan/1452573-longitudedelta) and [`latitudeDelta`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkcoordinatespan/1452417-latitudedelta) for a `MKCoordinateSpan` are measured in degrees. There are only 180 degrees of latitude from the north pole to the south pole, so using 200 for that parameter is not very sensible.

Since you want to show just the region of a city on the map, you can use [this other initialiser](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkcoordinateregion/1452245-init) that takes in distances in meters, if you know how big the cities that your app is handling usually are.

For example,

```
let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: cityLocation, latitudinalMeters: 30000, longitudinalMeters: 30000)
```

If your cities have varying sizes, or you don't know how big they are, then another way is to calculate the range of latitudes and longitudes of the hotels, and use that to create an `MKCoordinateSpan`.

```
var minLat: CLLocationDegrees = 90
var maxLat: CLLocationDegrees = -90
var minLong: CLLocationDegrees = 180
var maxLong: CLLocationDegrees = -180
for data in hotelListData {
    // ... you annotation code ...

    guard let hotel = data.hotel else { continue }
    if hotel.latitude < minLat { minLat = hotel.latitude }
    if hotel.latitude > maxLat { maxLat = hotel.latitude }
    if hotel.longitude < minLong { minLong = hotel.longitude }
    if hotel.longitude > maxLong { maxLong = hotel.longitude }
}
let latRange = max(0.01, maxLat - minLat) // if the range is too small, make it at least 0.01
let longRange = max(0.01, maxLong - minLong)
let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(
                           center: cityLocation,
                           span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: latRange, longitudeDelta: longRange)
```